# KeyError in constance package used in Django and PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, django, pycharm, django-constance

I am getting the following error when I try to run my debugger configuration on a Django project through a Docker container using Docker Compose. I can't find `AUTO_END_TIMEDELTA_MINS` anywhere on the web. Any idea what that might be?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-08-21T18:03:17.443221106Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/constance/base.py", line 14, in __getattr__
2023-08-21T18:03:17.443224978Z     if not len(settings.CONFIG[key]) in (2, 3):
2023-08-21T18:03:17.443227740Z KeyError: 'AUTO_END_TIMEDELTA_MINS'
```

My `settings.py` is following

```
import os
from datetime import timedelta

from hyperlocalgroceries.settings.constants import (
    BASE_DIR,
    TESTING,
    DEBUG,
    ENVIRONMENT,
)
from hyperlocalgroceries.settings.env import (
    SQL_ENGINE,
    SQL_DATABASE,
    SQL_USER,
    SQL_PASSWORD,
    SQL_HOST,
    SQL_PORT,
)

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ""

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

FRAMEWORK_APPS = [
    "dal",
    "dal_select2",
    "postgres_metrics.apps.PostgresMetrics",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.gis",
    "django_extensions",
    "django.contrib.humanize",
    "django_celery_results",
    "corsheaders",
]

INTERNAL_APPS = [
    "authentication",
    "common",
    "orders",
    "location",
    "activity",
    "cse",
    "status",
    "shopkeeper",
    "shop",
    "orders_v2",
    "customer",
    "rider",
    "bots_v2",
    "property",
    "household",
    "subscription",
    "prep",
    "finance",
    "media",
    "payments",
    "products",
    "transactions",
    "corporate",
    "queues",
    "auction",
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    "constance",
    "simple_history",
    "debug_toolbar",
    "django_tables2",
    "widget_tweaks",
    "constance.backends.database",
    "cacheops",
]

INSTALLED_APPS = FRAMEWORK_APPS + INTERNAL_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware",
    "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "hyperlocalgroceries.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "hyperlocalgroceries", "templates"),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "cse", "templates"),
        ],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "hyperlocalgroceries.wsgi.application"

if TESTING:
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite",
            "NAME": "_test_db",
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": SQL_ENGINE,
            "NAME": SQL_DATABASE,
            "USER": SQL_USER,
            "PASSWORD": SQL_PASSWORD,
            "HOST": SQL_HOST,
            "PORT": SQL_PORT,
        }
    }

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "min_length": 9,
        },
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "Asia/Karachi"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "authentication.User"

LOGIN_URL = "/admin/login/?next=/cse/"

#
# DRF
#

if TESTING:
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        "COERCE_DECIMAL_TO_STRING": False,
        "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
            "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
        ),
        "DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES": [
            "rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle",
            "rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle",
        ],
        "DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES": {
            "anon": "100/minute",
            "user": "100/minute",
        },
    }
    INSTALLED_APPS.append("rest_framework.authtoken")
elif DEBUG:
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        "COERCE_DECIMAL_TO_STRING": False,
        "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
            "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
        ],
        "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
            "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
            "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
            "drf_firebase_auth.authentication.FirebaseAuthentication",
        ),
        "DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES": [
            "rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle",
            "rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle",
        ],
        "DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES": {
            "anon": "100/minute",
            "user": "100/minute",
        },
        "DATETIME_FORMAT": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        "DATE_FORMAT": "%Y-%m-%d",
        "TIME_FORMAT": "%H:%M:%S",
        "EXCEPTION_HANDLER": "common.utils.rest_custom_exception_handler.custom_exception_handler",
    }
    INSTALLED_APPS.append("drf_firebase_auth")
    INSTALLED_APPS.append("rest_framework.authtoken")
else:
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        "COERCE_DECIMAL_TO_STRING": False,
        "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
            "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
        ],
        "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
            "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
            "drf_firebase_auth.authentication.FirebaseAuthentication",
        ),
        "DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES": [
            "rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle",
            "rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle",
        ],
        "DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES": {
            "anon": "100/minute",
            "user": "100/minute",
        },
        "DATETIME_FORMAT": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        "DATE_FORMAT": "%Y-%m-%d",
        "TIME_FORMAT": "%H:%M:%S",
        "EXCEPTION_HANDLER": "common.utils.rest_custom_exception_handler.custom_exception_handler",
    }
    INSTALLED_APPS.append("drf_firebase_auth")

#
# CORS
#

if ENVIRONMENT == "PROD":
    CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    ]
    CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    ]
else:
    CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True


#
# STATIC FILES
#

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "hyperlocalgroceries", "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "cse", "static"),
]

#
# JWT
#

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=30),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=90),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True,
}

#
# DEBUG TOOL BAR
#


def show_toolbar(request):
    return DEBUG and not TESTING


DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    "SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK": show_toolbar,
}

#
# OTHERS
#

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

SIMPLE_HISTORY_REVERT_DISABLED = True

DJANGO_TABLES2_TEMPLATE = "django_tables2/bootstrap4.html"

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db"
```

Comment: Update code with docker compose setting you are using

Answer (score 0):

`setting.py` giving very less idea about the problem, you module called constance is causing this error and this needs deep debugging but you can try to add this code in your `settings.py`:

```
CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
   'AUTO_END_TIMEDELTA_MINS': (False, "<Any String>"),
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I can run the containers without PyCharm with no exceptions. I ran it and checked if I am missing out any environment variables and found out that there is a dictionary by the name of `CONSTANCE_CONFIG`. I added it in PyCharm but it's not working.

Comment: @AbdullahNafees I don't think PyCharm has anything to do with this. You seem to be running separate containers and with docker compose. I believe it could be docker compose issue.

Comment: @Ahtisham I fixed it. It was a matter of understanding the project. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been resolved by using the whole `settings` folder in the debugger configuration in PyCharm instead of the separate file like you normally would because that's how the project has been set up. I didn't know about it because I have transitioned from a PHP backend to Django in 2 days.

Also, refrain from adding environment variables manually in PyCharm's Project Settings menu when you connect to the Python interpreter defined in your Docker Compose container. PyCharm handles that itself. It might not make sense but you can comment your questions and I will update the answer.

BTW I am using PyCharm 2023.2.